# Picklist values aren't matching in row level formula

Tags: reporting, picklist, report-formula

In a lead report, I have a row level formula called 'Industry Grouping'. The formula for this field is:

`IF(TEXT(INDUSTRY) == "Candy and other Confection", "Candy", "Other")`

A filter on the report selects only INDUSTRY picklist values of "Candy and other Confection"

The expected result of this report should be a list of leads with the Industry value of "Candy and other Confection" and all results should have an Industry Grouping value of 'Candy'.

However, the report returns 26 total records. 15 with an Industry Grouping of "Candy" and 11 with an Industry Grouping of "Other".

As I understand it, this should return all 26 records with an Industry Grouping of "Candy"

What would cause these picklist values to not match?

I also tried changing my formula to:

`IF(ISPICKVAL(INDUSTRY, "Candy and other Confection"), "Candy", "Other")`

This produces the same results as above.

Here is a screenshot of my filter:
[image]

Here is my formula:
[image]

Lastly here is a preview of the output:
[image]

Comment: Any chance you have two fields, both named `Industry` ?